# EF6 Code First - Configure One-to-One relationship with unmatched foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm using Code First to define the schema of an existing database.  The problem I'm having is that they key names in the tables don't quite align.  This works fine with one-to-many relationships because I can use the `HasForeignKey()` method, but there does't seem to be an equivalent for one-to-one relationships.  My table definitions are:

```
namespace Data.Mappings {

    internal class DocumentTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Document> {

        public DocumentTypeConfiguration() {
            ToTable("ProsDocs");

            HasKey(m => m.Id);

            Property(m => m.Id)
                .HasColumnName("ProsDocId")
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

            // ---- This is the foreign key ----
            Property(m => m.TypeId)
                .HasColumnName("ProsDocTypeId")
                .HasMaxLength(3);

            HasRequired(d => d.DocType)
                .WithRequiredDependent(dt => dt.Document);
                // I need to specify here that the foreign key is named "DocTypeId" and not "DocType_Id"
        }
    }

    internal class DocTypeTypeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<DocType> {

        public DocTypeTypeConfiguration() {
            ToTable("DocType");

            HasKey(m => m.Id);

            // ---- This is the "child" end of the foreign key ----
            Property(m => m.Id)
                .HasColumnName("DocTypeId")
                .HasMaxLength(4);

            Property(m => m.FullName)
                .HasColumnName("DocTypeDesc")
                .HasMaxLength(255);

            Property(m => m.Priority)
                .HasColumnName("DocPriority");

            // Or would it be easier to define it here?
//            HasRequired(m => m.Document)
//                .WithRequiredDependent(d => d.DocType);
        }
    }
}
```

To clarify the model, each `Document` has a `DocType`, with the foreign key relationship of `Document.ProsDocTypeId --> DocType.Id`.

Is there a way to define what the column names are for keys for one-to-one relationships?

**EDIT:**  I guess my schema isn't clear.

```
dbo.DocType
-----------
DocTypeId char(4) (PK)
DocTypeDesc varchar(255)

dbo.ProsDocs
------------
ProsDocId int (PK)
ProsDocTypeId char(4)
```

Basically, I need the resulting query to look like this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProsDocId] AS [ProsDocId], 
    [Extent2].[DocTypeId] AS [DocTypeId]
    FROM  [dbo].[ProsDocs] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProsDocTypeId] = [Extent2].[DocTypeId]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ProsId] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

But instead, because EF assumes I want to use the primary key (`dbo.ProsDocs.ProsDocId`) instead of a foreign key (`dbo.ProsDocs.DocTypeId`), the query it generates is this:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ProsDocId] AS [ProsDocId], 
    [Extent2].[DocTypeId] AS [DocTypeId]
    FROM  [dbo].[ProsDocs] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProsDocId] = [Extent2].[ProsDocTypeId]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ProsId] = @EntityKeyValue1
```

The difference lies here:

Ideal query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProsDocTypeId] = [Extent2].[DocTypeId]
```

Current query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProsDocId] = [Extent2].[ProsDocTypeId]
```

I need to create a *one-to-one relationship* between `dbo.ProsDocs.ProsDocTypeId` and `dbo.DocType.DocTypeId`.  The problem EF is having with it is that it wants to create the relationship using only the primary keys, not foreign keys.  How do I specify the column name of the foreign key such that *each `Document` has exactly one `DocType`?*

Comment: which one is the principal (the entity that must exist first) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `Document` is the principal and `DocType` is the dependent, then you either need to

- Have this configuration on `Document`

  ```
  HasRequired(d => d.DocType).WithRequiredPrincipal(dt => dt.Document);
  ```
- Or this configuration on `DocType`

  ```
  HasRequired(dt => dt.Document).WithRequiredDependent(d => d.DocType);
  ```

And remove `TypeId` / `ProsDocTypeId` property from `Document` as the principal can't have foreign key id to dependent, unless it's not a constraint, just a normal column.

**update**

Entity:

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    // This entity is a principal. It can't have foreign key id to dependent.
    // public string TypeId { get; set; }
    public DocType DocType { get; set; }
}
```

Linq:

```
db.Documents.Include(d => d.DocType)
```

Query:

```
 SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [Extent1].[ProsDocId] AS [ProsDocId],
    [Extent2].[DocTypeId] AS [DocTypeId],
    FROM  [dbo].[ProsDocs] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DocType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProsDocId] = [Extent2].[DocTypeId]
```

**update 2**

To achieve your ideal query, the relationship that you needed is one to many. One `DocType` can have many `Document`.

```
public class Document
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string TypeId { get; set; }
    public DocType DocType { get; set; }
}
public class DocType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

The configuration on `Document`.

Change this:

```
HasRequired(d => d.DocType).WithRequiredDependent(dt => dt.Document);
```

Into:

```
HasRequired(d => d.DocType).WithMany(dt => dt.Documents).HasForeignKey(d => d.TypeId);
```

Linq:

```
db.Documents.Include(d => d.DocType)
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    1 AS [C1],
    [Extent1].[ProsDocId] AS [ProsDocId],
    [Extent1].[ProsDocTypeId] AS [ProsDocTypeId],
    [Extent2].[DocTypeId] AS [DocTypeId],
    FROM  [dbo].[ProsDocs] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DocType] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ProsDocTypeId] = [Extent2].DocTypeId]
```

Comment: That's exactly my problem.  The primary key of `Document`, as my model shows, is `ProsDocId`.  The relationship should be between `Document.TypeId` and `DocType.Id`, or in other words, `dbo.Document` is the principal, while `dbo.DocType.DocTypeId` is the foreign key.  See my updated question.

Comment: @StephenCollins, I think you are confused with the definition of one to one relationship, in this kind of relationship, as you mentioned (Document is the principal), the principal **can't** have another column that refers to dependent like `Document.TypeId` to `DocType.Id`, the relationship should be between `Document.Id` to `DocType.Id`, please check [this one to one relationship](http://www.databaseprimer.com/pages/relationship_1to1/) where `Customer` table (the principal) can't have another column like `CustomerDetailId`, my answer remains the same, just add the entity and query

Comment: Whether or not I'm incorrect about my verbiage, this answer is still not what solves my problem. I need the resulting query to read as the first one in my question ("Ideal query").  That query is exactly what I would execute in custom SQL; I need the equivalent in Linq.

Comment: @StephenCollins, I updated again, what you need is one to many

Comment: Yes, your updated answer is exactly what I need.  That feels sort of "backwards" to me, so it didn't even cross my mind.  It's definitely correct, though.  Thank you!